# Missing netstandard 2.0 assembly error on blank Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I'm getting an error when creating a blank Xamarin.Forms project in VS where the netstandard assembly isn't being referenced, and cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

The errors I'm getting in the app are:

- CS0012 C# The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
  You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
  Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
- CS0006 C# Metadata    file '..\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ref\App.dll'
  could not be found)

I have tried, to no avail:

- Updating the NETStandard.Library package to 2.0 or higher through NuGet (works for the App.iOS and App.Android projects but not the main App - it says "Blocked by project" for anything above v1.6.1)
- Adding a reference to the requested netstandard version in the csproj 
  `<Reference Include="netstandard"/>` as suggested here: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/542#issuecomment-344591026
- Adding `<Reference Include="System.IdentityModel"/>` to the csproj as suggested here: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/542#issuecomment-501309019
- Changing `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` to
  `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>` as suggested here: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/542#issuecomment-465375220
- Deleting the bin, obj, .suo, and .vs folders and restarting VS, as well as
  creating an entirely new Xamarin.Forms blank project
- Updating Xamarin.Essentials and Xamarin.Forms in NuGet
- Updating to VS Community 2019 16.5.0 Preview 2.0 (where I'd read this issue had been fixed; I've unfortunately misplaced the thread this was in)

This is my csproj (default with the exception of the AutoGenerateBindingRedirects, which was suggested in the comments):

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.3.0.908675" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="ViewModels\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Anyone have any idea what to do about this? Most of the answers I've found either don't work or are several years old and are alleged to have been fixed with newer VS versions.

Here's a link to my detailed output logs:

VS Community 19 Preview: https://privatebin.net/?c7c4cd6123e0edd7#5qYTwaKSyGKBMgU3beshk3Xgx52nyCyAYcsq63uRfWWT

VS Community 19: https://privatebin.net/?2cf9d7ab07e8a4fb#5UkwWhxKFPDGnTtVdZuawkQLMRNe4qvJLeuaBrFrPoJf

Comment: which windows 10 version do you use? update your windows 10 to 1909

Comment: I am already on 1909.

Comment: delete obj/bin folders and reopen solution. the "PackageReference Include" thing is buggy as hell.

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to say I've tried that already also, hasn't helped unfortunately but I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: sometimes simply closing a solution and reopen helps.

Comment: As I said in the question, I already tried that (many times)

Comment: Add the line `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` to PropertyGroup. If it still doesn't work , you could report teh issue to IDE support team . Help->Send Feedback->Report an issue .

Comment: Still doesn't work, I'll update the csproj in the question and send that bug report though

Comment: Could you please set Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->"MSBuild project build output verbosity" set to detailed and build again and post the detailed build log in the output window?

Comment: Updated the question with a link to the output log.

Comment: @kaci Seems like you are using Visual Studio 2019 preview version. Could you please download the latest  release Community version and try again?

Comment: VS Community was what I was using in the first place with the same errors, but I'll reinstall and send the logs

Comment: Updated question with the VS Community 2019 output log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem after two weeks of personal suffering and 2 hours spent with someone experienced with Xamarin! The issue was that I had two different versions of dotnet installed (one in the C: drive and one in my E: drive where I also keep program files). Entered `dotnet --version` in cmd only to see that the version it found was Ancient (1.x), and then `dotnet --list-sdks` to find the duplicate one. After deleting the old SDK in the E: drive and rechecking my dotnet version the error vanished!